# Gmail following links (Gmail-content-sampling)

Tags: gmail

I'm getting a click event from SendGrid for every link in an email sent to Gmail users, and it is definitely not me clicking the links, I even get the first click event to my SendGrid webhook before SendGrid sends the delivered event to me.

This adds needless hits to both the webhook endpoint and to the pages it hits, I can filter out the click events so I won't get false click counts by filtering for user agents with "Gmail-content-sampling" in it
as the user agent supplied is

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
> like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.246
> Gmail-content-sampling

However it would still needlessly hit the site umpteen thousand times in a few minutes (I don't think that will agree with the standard click here to validate email address links) and I don't want to have to add a block user agent per for every request.

Although filtering would be a problem if other providers do the same thing or Gmail change the user agent.

I have tried adding rel="nofollow" to the links but it still does it.

Anyone experience this/know how to get gmail to f-off ?

**Edit:**

As at 10th August google have undone their stuff up.

Comment: I'm in a similar boat.  The gmail content sampler is clicking our unsubscribe links!  I've also got a thread going on the [G-Suite admin forum](https://support.google.com/a/thread/62011426?hl=en) but it hasn't provided much of an answer yet.

Comment: It's also interesting to note that searching Google for "Gmail-content-sampling" returns only 10 results, the top two are from our forum posts so I think this is a new behaviour from Gmail.

Comment: This definitely seems to be new behavior from Gmail. We've had hundreds of customers get unsubscribed without their knowledge, all within the past week.

Comment: I just did more testing, this appears to be resolved now, (I'm using https://webhook.site/ to get webhook post data from SendGrid), no more obnoxious content sampling.

This may be new behaviour, I get 2 hits on any new link on clicked, from Gmail web UI.

One from my browser and one from 
useragent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
"ip": "74.125.210.65"

That IP is a google proxy server apparently

So we need to debounce link click counts to stop googles douchebaggery artificially inflating counts.

Comment: Please add all additional information to the question itself by [edit]ing it, or create an answer  if the matter has been resolved to your satisfaction. You can  create a partial answer from information which is part of or helpful for the answering process but does not completely solve it.